# Check if Variable Exists in JLD File

Tags: julia

If I save a variable to a JLD file like this:

```
file["myVar"] = data
```

How can I check if it exists?

```
if exists(file, "myVar")
    println( file["myVar"] )
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to test your code, I have noticed `exists` is defined in `HDF5.jl` package and not in `JLD.jl` package. So, perhaps if you just do a `using HDF5` beforehand, the code in the OP should work.

Comment: And, if the value of `myVar` is to be printed, it might be better to `println(read(file["myVBar"]))` (notice the `read`).

Comment: Is there a way to read all variable names saved in the file without parsing the variable data?  I will have to check later but maybe you know.

Comment: @BAR, if this answered your question, please mark it as answered so it doesn't continue to show up as unanswered. Thanks!